# Pass parameter from .Net to Java method

Tags: java, c#, xml

I have added one assembly into .Net API solution. Assembly code is written in java language.
There is a method in assembly where method expects Item  parameter as defined below

```
public partial class ValueType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private object itemField;   
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Text", typeof(string), Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("XmlDoc", typeof(object), Order=0)]
        public object Item {
            get {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
            }
        }
```

And I am trying to pass xmldoument type object  as parameter into the method  but getting below error

```
public XmlDocument connectToBMC(XmlDocument xml)
{           
            try
            {                      
               Item.Input =xml ;
               Out= client.executeProcess("MyGrid", ":BMC_PS-SA-Tests:Mediation_layer_test", Item);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Debug(ex.Message);
            }
            return xml;
}
```

Error:

```
There was an error in serializing body of message executeProcessRequest:'There was an error generating the XML document.'.
```

[inner exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nynCq.png)

Stack trace:

> Server stack trace: 
>          at  System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean
>   isRequest)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object
>   returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message
>   message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32
>   maxSizeQuota)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message
>   message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32
>   messageOffset)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message
>   message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> ```
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> ```
>
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorService.executeProcess(executeProcessRequest
>   request)
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorServiceClient.MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorService.executeProcess(executeProcessRequest
>   request) in C:\Rahul
>   Biswas\MediationAPI\MediationAPI.BusinessLogic\Service
>   References\BMCServiceProxy\Reference.cs:line 1573
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorServiceClient.executeProcess(String
>   gridName, String processName, ParametersType parameters) in C:\Rahul
>   Biswas\MediationAPI\MediationAPI.BusinessLogic\Service
>   References\BMCServiceProxy\Reference.cs:line 1581
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCMessageHandler.connectToBMC(XmlDocument
>   xml) in C:\Rahul
>   Biswas\MediationAPI\MediationAPI.BusinessLogic\BMCMessageHandler.cs:line
>   65

Once trying to pass string xmldoc. OuterXml like string as parameter into the method but getting below error

```
string xml1 = xml.OuterXml;

        try
        {                      
           pt.Input =xml1  ;
           pt = client.executeProcess("MyGrid", ":BMC_PS-SA-Tests:Mediation_layer_test", Item);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Debug(ex.Message);
        }
        return xml;
```

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException stack trace:
>
> ```
> Server stack trace: 
>    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
> ```
>
> operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> ```
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> ```
>
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorService.executeProcess(executeProcessRequest
>   request)
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorServiceClient.MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorService.executeProcess(executeProcessRequest
>   request) in C:\Rahul
>   Biswas\MediationAPI\MediationAPI.BusinessLogic\Service
>   References\BMCServiceProxy\Reference.cs:line 1573
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCServiceProxy.OrchestratorServiceClient.executeProcess(String
>   gridName, String processName, ParametersType parameters) in C:\Rahul
>   Biswas\MediationAPI\MediationAPI.BusinessLogic\Service
>   References\BMCServiceProxy\Reference.cs:line 1581
>          at MediationAPI.BusinessLogic.BMCMessageHandler.connectToBMC(XmlDocument
>   xml) in C:\Rahul
>   Biswas\MediationAPI\MediationAPI.BusinessLogic\BMCMessageHandler.cs:line
>   65

xml.OuterXml actually contanis

```
<root><event><event_action>closeIncident</event_action><entity_id>e9cf1bfcd5275100cc5ce0c8d463e486</entity_id><source_system></source_system><sent_timestamp></sent_timestamp></event><incidentRecord><caused_code><name>Testing</name></caused_code><resolution_category><name> Testing </name></resolution_category><resolution_subcategory><name> Testing </name></resolution_subcategory><resolved_by><user_id>Devi Nair</user_id></resolved_by><close_code>Closed/Resolved by Caller</close_code><closed_at>2016-05-24 14:00:06</closed_at><knowledge>false</knowledge><resolved_at>20-04-2016 15:41:36</resolved_at><mitigation_notes></mitigation_notes><close_notes>test</close_notes><mitigation_reason></mitigation_reason><resolve_children></resolve_children><mitigation_date></mitigation_date><external_entity_id>621943</external_entity_id><number>SNI0063168</number><caller><user_id>aglsd@agl.com.au</user_id></caller><status>7</status><status_reason>Confirmed</status_reason><requested_for><user_id>aglsd@agl.com.au</user_id></requested_for><organisation><code>4758</code></organisation><impact>2</impact><urgency>4</urgency><configuration_item><code></code></configuration_item><location><name>AGL Kolkata</name></location><service_type><name>Other</name></service_type><symptom><name></name></symptom><incident_type>Enquiry</incident_type><short_description>s</short_description><description></description><additional_comments></additional_comments><parent_incident><number></number><external_entity_id></external_entity_id></parent_incident><problem><number></number><external_entity_id></external_entity_id></problem><change_request><number></number><external_entity_id></external_entity_id></change_request><caused_by_change><number></number><external_entity_id></external_entity_id></caused_by_change><directed_from_kb><number></number></directed_from_kb><watch_lists><watch_list><user_id>d791017</user_id></watch_list></watch_lists><attachments><attachment><filename></filename><content></content></attachment></attachments><affectedCIs><affected_ci><name></name><code></code><organisation><code></code></organisation></affected_ci></affectedCIs><priority>3</priority></incidentRecord></root>";
```

Can anyone  please help me understand the issue?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Added stack trace for both situations

Comment: For the `There was an error generating the XML document` exception, there should be an `InnerException` that explains the problem in more detail.  Please share that.

Comment: Added inner exception  
For the There was an error generating the XML document exception.Please click the inner exception link for checking.

Comment: I got some clue..... whenever I am trying to save the xml.innertext into a string and sending <root><event>Abc<event><root> , all special character '< , >' are changed with &lt ,&gt  so getting error. I want to send <root><event>Abc<event><root>  within string without any change. any work around to on that.